# How to draw grass to be 3D printed (resin)?

Tags: particles, 3d-printing

I am drawing up a small scale island about 30mm in diameter which will be 3D printed in resin as part of a diarama scene. The island needs to be covered in grass.
I am struggling to get achieve grass, I have tried using poke but not giving a very natural look.
I tried using the particle system with hair but cant get the rotation to work to make the hair go straight up....?

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw geometry on other geometry by mixing [Weight Painting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/introduction.html) and [Geometry Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/introduction.html).

Draw weights on your geometry.

[image: Island-like geometry with weight paints leaving a line in the middle]

Then create a Geometry node setup that looks something like this:

[image: Simple geometry node setup that distributes points on geometry and instances a cone per point]

The Name on the [Named Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/read/named_attribute.html)-node is the same name that your weight paint vertex group name have. The [cone](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/primitives/cone.html) can be any geometry that looks like grass. It is important that you have a [Realize Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/realize_instances.html)-node as it will not export the geometry for 3D printing otherwise.

[image: Cones distributed on island-like geometry]

If you want the grass to extend out from the geometry rather than all pointing upwards you can align the rotation using the following modification:

[image: Aligning the cones to the smooth normal]

The [Set Shade Smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/write/set_shade_smooth.html)-node is setting making it so that the normals we align the cones to are smoother than they would be without it.

[image: Cones distributed on island-like geometry align to smooth normals]

Comment: Thank you, this looks exactly like what I need.
I have never used that panel before, I have tried recreating what you have but how do I add the Named Attribute & Cone, when I try it comes in looking different?

PS. Is there no easy way to just make the particle-system-hair rotate upwards?

Comment: The screenshots come from Blender 4.0.2. I add the nodes by pressing shift+A and typing (searching) the node name. The numbers in the inputs on the nodes where more or less selected at random. I have no experience with the particle system. Perhaps someone else can write an answer that uses it.

Comment: Thanks, still cant add the name attribute box...?
I have this setup on the moment but not working correctly.
https://imgur.com/a/mQbR8Nm

Comment: The Geometry Node-modifier needs to go on the "island". No idea why the Named Attribute-node isn't popping up. In the Geometry Node panel menu it should be under "Add" -> "Geometry" -> "Read" -> "Named Attribute".

Comment: These are the options i have in Add - Geometry
https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with the link. Are you using Blender 4.0.2?

Comment: Im using version 3.01

Comment: In 3.0 it looks like you need to use [the Group Input node and assign the weights from the modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html#named-attributes).

Comment: Its ok, I downloaded the latest and have it all setup now and working.
Thank you !!!!
Muchly appreciated

Comment: Great to hear! If this answer solved your problem, please [mark it as "accepted"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).